# Boto's get_all_images function

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I tried to load list of AWS images using Python boto library. So my code is like

```
con = boto.connect_ec2(user, pasw)
con.get_all_instances()
con.get_all_images()
```

Problem is that, get_all_instances() works fine, but get_all_images() is not responding. When stop application from kbd, I see

```
  File "eagle/main.py", line 102, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "eagle/main.py", line 97, in main
    return request, process_request(request)
  File "eagle/main.py", line 45, in process_request
    request = each().process_request(request)
  File "/home/rustem/projects/eagle.2.0/eagle/../eagle/middlewares/standard.py", line 64, in process_request
    request.images = con.get_all_images()
  File "/home/rustem/envs/eagle.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 171, in get_all_images
    [('item', Image)], verb='POST')
  File "/home/rustem/envs/eagle.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1063, in get_list
    body = response.read()
  File "/home/rustem/envs/eagle.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 411, in read
    self._cached_response = httplib.HTTPResponse.read(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 541, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 590, in _read_chunked
    value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 647, in _safe_read
    chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It seems like Boto's function is not working, AWS API is not responding. Have anyone similar problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why does it "seem like Boto's function is not working"? From the traceback, it looks like it's still working. There are many thousands of images and no pagination so the request takes a very long time. I would avoid it unless absolutely necessary.  Can you use filters to return fewer results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason was that the get_all_images function returns all images from AWS, so it works about few minutes. I started to user filters and now it takes reasonably time.